# Run lab test for all test subfolders

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, hapi.js

I'm refactoring one backend at my company and I'm modularizing it as much as possible. My structure can be defined as a monorepo composed of several local submodules and one or two main modules that requires them(the submodules). Let's illustrate this:

- root

  - main
  - package.json
  - stuff that uses submoduleA
  - stuff that uses submoduleB
  - test
  - modules

    - submoduleA
    - package.json
    - code
    - test
  - submoduleB

    - package.json
    - test

As you can see, each module has it's own tests, `package.json`, and dependencies. Everything works flawlessly within them (running `npm test` inside the folder of a module, for example). I'm using `lab` and `code` for testing.

What I want is to be able to do is going to the root of the project, run `npm test` and run all the tests for all the submodules and the main module. Basically run all the test under any test folder in one go.

The problems that I found so far are:
- Currently only the files under the target test directory are being run. I don't even know how to run all the test at once. My command looks like `lab src/main/test --reporter console --threshold 100 --assert code`

What I'm doing now is putting all the test under the same test directory and make relative requirements for everything. This is very inconvenient because makes test fragile with all those `../../../some/away/path` requires and that stuff.

Any advice for keeping the code modular, and being able to run all the test at once will be very welcome. Thank you very much.

I asked this a week ago on hapijs repository, so if you want to answer there too it would be fine: https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/397

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making submoduleA and submoduleB stand alone node modules, then you can install and use with the main module when required.  This way you are testing each part in isolation and then together which should yield the same outcome and will enable you to run tests more easier.

Comment: I have some submodules that work that way, they are managed as local npm modules, and are actually installed to node_modules folder. They have their own test folder, and I can test each individually. But, I don't have any method to test the entire thing in one go. Could you expand on the second part? Testing them together?

Comment: By testing top level module you are testing all modules together